# Psr-4 : namespace and spl autoload

Tags: php, namespaces, spl-autoload-register

Okay, as I browse around there are lots of posts and answers on the line. To my understanding

psr-0: SPL autoload only

psr-4: SPL autoload + namespace

Most of the answers contain LONG methods. psr-4 should not be HARD to implement since it purposes is to simplify file structure yet remaining its own advantage.

I have a structure like this `project\view\main.php`

in `main.php`

```
namespace project\view;
class main {
    .......
}
```

out of the project folder which is my root directory, i have a `index.php`

```
spl_autoload_register( function ($ClassName) {
    require $ClassName . '.php';
});
$main = new project\view\main();
```

Question: Am I doing it right with psr-4 or am I still missing something from the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the specification `PSR-0`[[1]](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) is deprecated (since 2014-10-21) and is replaced by `PSR-4`

From `PSR-4` documentation:

> This PSR describes a specification for autoloading classes from file
>   paths. It is fully interoperable, and can be used in addition to any
>   other autoloading specification, including PSR-0. This PSR also
>   describes where to place files that will be autoloaded according to
>   the specification.

http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

If you want the full rationnale for the specification change you can consult the [PSR-4 meta document](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-meta.md).

If you want to see working example, you can search at the [same location](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md)

My ultimate recommandation would be to take a look at [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) and let it handle it. You would only have to include the automatically generated `autoload.php` file to have fully functionnal autoloading.